# How to call functions from a python module in a different folder?

Tags: python

My project structure is something like this:

```
/project-name
    app.py
    /python-modules
        login.py
        home.py
```

I want to import some functions present in login.py and home.py into app.py.

I tried to run `from python-modules.login import *`, but no luck.

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in `python-modules`?

Comment: Just created in project root directory and python-modules folder

Comment: Now try importing again.

Comment: I don't think you need a `__init__.py` in the root directory, unless your project is a package but it doesn't look like a package according to your project's structure.

Comment: @Ipozo ran this command ```from python-modules.login import *```. In login.py, I had a function name def login():, and in app.py, I used login(), but it is giving syntax error.

Comment: Well, I think you're missing some important details in your question then. I thought you were having an `ImportError` or something related to imports. You better check the syntax of `login()`.

Comment: login() function was earlier in app.py, but since I wanted to break my code into smaller pieces, I created the submodules folder. But now if it is the same function, then I am getting syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution Just create blank (empty) `__init__.py` file in both folders i.e. project-name and python modules.

Comment: Created, then after that?

Comment: Then it will work

Answer (score 0):

I should change the name of your packages (directories) : it is not a good practice to have dashes in the name of your package (see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id38))

Comment: I did change the dash to underscore, but didn't change here in the question. Thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I din't see that detail. Package names must be valid Python identifiers, so you can't use dashes in packages names. You should change it into an underscore: `python_modules`. That was the reason for your `SyntaxError`.